# Notification Infinite Loop

Tags: android, notifications

Each time I send a notification the device acts as if it the notification has been sent an infinite amount of times. That is, the ringtone and vibrate go off continually until I open the notification menu. I can get this behavior to stop if I comment out the notification.flag |= line but then I am unable to use the auto-cancel flag. Any ideas on what is causing this?

```
         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                 .setSmallIcon(resourceID)
                 .setContentTitle(title)
                 .setContentText(contentText)
                 .setSound(soundUri, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
                 .setVibrate(CommonUtilities.VIBRATE_PATTERN); 

         Notification notification = mBuilder.build();


         /* comment this out to stop the infinite notification loop */

         notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS 
                 | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
                 | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;


         Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
         PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, CommonUtilities.REQUEST_NOTIFICATION, intent, 0);
         String pref = getSharedPreferences(CommonUtilities.NOTIFICATION_PEF, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("incoming", contentText);
         notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title ,pref, activity);

        notification.number += 1;
         //Display notification
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Per Pavlos suggestion I checked my flags again and I think the issue is that I'm mixing/or-ing  flags and defaults together and that is throwing off the bitwise operation.

Changed to:
`notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;`
`notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
                 | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE; `

Answer (score 3):

Hmm well you should check your flags again!

> FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE
>   Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if you want the sound and/or vibration play each time the notification is sent, even if it has not been canceled before that.

So my guess is that with this flag you will get your notification to vibrate all the time.

From the official docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html